# How to generate CNT bond-type information for LAMMPS intial file?

Tags: lammps, vmd

I have just started working with VMD, and I figured out how to generate a Carbon Nano Tube (CNT) in VMD and save it's atom positions to use as initial file in LAMMPS. My question is, if you know of any simple way in VMD so that I can get the bonding and angle data as well, to use in my LAMMPS initial file?

in other words, after creating a CNT in VMD, How can I generate a data file containing not only the atom positions, but also bonding and angle information in the format of LAMMPS initial input file?

Best Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **Tkconsole** under extension and follow

```
topo retypebonds
topo guessdihedrals
topo writelammpsdata lmp.data full
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Do you know of anyway I can create a diffent nanotube rather than Hegzagonal lattice in VMD? I mean is there any way I can change the lattice to whatever I want?

Comment: Since I can easily get the input file for LAMMPS from VMD, I 'm looking for away to generate my own lattice shape like for example triangular lattice nanotube. Is that possible?

Comment: @DelaramNematollahi kindly create a new question in forum regarding triangular nanotube

Comment: Hi I did that here is the link thank a lot: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/8690/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-non-predefined-nanotube-in-vmd

Answer (score 3):

If you like me prefer working in the `python` ecosystem, I suggest using [lammps-interface](https://github.com/peteboyd/lammps_interface) and [Atomic Simulation Environment (ASE)](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/).

[lammps-interface](https://github.com/peteboyd/lammps_interface) is a python code that interfaces crystal structures in `cif` format to `lammps` input files.

It is easy to install and use, simply pip install it and run:

```
lammps-interface cif_file.cif
```

By default, this gives you the input files for [the Universal Force Field (UFF)](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00051a040). There are a few other options, including the [Dreiding force field](https://doi.org/10.1021/j100389a010).

If you want to convert your crystal structure to cif format, use [Atomic Simulation Environment (ASE)](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/).